# Django channels cannot import name RequestAborted from exceptions

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-channels, channel

Using daphne here's my setup:

**PROCFILE:**

```
 web: daphne my_application.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
```

---

**SETTINGS**

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django.contrib.humanize',
        'channels',
        'django_summernote',
        ....
    ]

     CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
        "default": {
            "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
            "CONFIG": {
                "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')],
            }
        }
    } 

    ASGI_APPLICATION = "my_application.routing.application"
```

---

**ROUTING FILE:**

```
    from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
    from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
    from django.conf.urls import url

    application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
        'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    url(*),
                    ....
                ]
            )
        ),
    })
```

---

**ASGI.PY - WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS**

```
  """
    ASGI entrypoint. Configures Django and then runs the application
    defined in the ASGI_APPLICATION setting.
    """

    import os
    import django

    # HERE IT THROWS THE IMPORT ERROR
    from channels.routing import get_default_application

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_application.settings")
    django.setup()
    application = get_default_application()
```

---

**REQUIREMENTS:**

```
    ...
    channels
    channels_redis
    ...
```

So, using the latest 2.(2?) package I believe which I just verified has the source code required.

---

**IMPORT ERROR**

```
  from channels.exceptions import RequestAborted, RequestTimeout
  ImportError: cannot import name 'RequestAborted'
```

I clearly have the right package and this is available per the source code so wtf is going on here.....?

Answer (score 12):

As @chander mentioned: problem is that you install django-channels, when you were already having channels.
to solve problem run:

> pip uninstall django-channels

> pip uninstall channels

> pip install channels

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you did a:

> pip install django-channels

whereas you should have done

> pip install channels

To install the latest version of channels.

I had a similar problem - in the end I blew away my venv and pyenv and reinstalled - which fixed the issue.  The problem started when I accidentally installed django-channels when I already had channels installed.

Comment: nahi yaar chander, baat nahi ban rahi.